# Caching Google Map markers/coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cache

I have thousands of markers - I need to cache them and use *show-hide* tactics to only show like 100 markers at once but I have trouble with caching.

Adding all single markers/points to an array and if map is dragged or zoomed, then loop through the array to see it has already been loaded and then load all new markers that are not in that array is rather expensive.

How should I solve this caching issue?

How to load only markers/points/coordinates that haven't been loaded yet?

---

Could I benefit from grid system? *A.k.a* load all markers on that part of grid and cache grid - this would keep the array of *already loaded areas/points* much shorter.

Comment: what do you mean by 'caching'? are you using client side geometry? If you are, I would recommend that you use a server side tool to generate the view such as a KML, a Fusion Table or a WMS.

Comment: @HenWagner This _problem_ is pretty much killing all my hard work: every time map is panned or zoomed, **all** markers in map viewport are reloaded every single time. I need to _"cache"_ markers so that **only** these markers are loaded that haven't been loaded yet. Could you help me to figure this out?

Comment: @HenWagner Markers coordinates are sent to browser via ajax and is then placed on map via `JS`. All markers are also inside areas/polygons, maybe I could use them to check what markers have loaded and what not?

Comment: Can you use cookies to keep track of which markers the end user has already loaded? Or a session id or something?

Comment: @barrycarter I need to _"cache"_ markers only for _"one page load"_ which means that everything should _reset_ back to normal when page is refreshed because markers count and position is changing regulary. I could push and store them in array but how would I check if marker has already been loaded? Send the array of loaded markers to server, check there and send back only markers that haven't been loaded? This is the issue for me..

Comment: Ah, OK, I got it. You want to respond to pan and zoom events on the map canvas, adding markers as necessary.

Comment: @barrycarter Yes, that's correct. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Sadly, no. My approach would be to use server-side tiles, but that wouldn't give you real google markers, just images with red points or whatever on them.